# What are these wires for?

Tags: lcd

I have a Dell monitor I took apart to examine the LCD for a future project and it has these 4 wires coming out of the side of the LCD marked LRB. After examining the board that I removed the LCD from I can't figure out what they are for.[image: Both Wires]

Comment: Maybe it's the backlight

Answer (score 2):

Those wires are connected into the backlight components of the LCD panel. On newer panels these may provide power to the LEDs that light the panel from the sides or rear.

Other types of LCD panels used gas discharge type tubes to light the panel from along the edges. In that case the wires would be connecting into a high voltage power supply on the electronics part of the monitor. If the wires are small and have a silicone rubbery type of insulation then it is highly likely that these connect into the gas discharge tube type of backlight.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend these connections?

Comment: It may be possible. Your picture suggests that these are the high voltage type silicon insulated wires. What ever means you used to extend the wires would have to use extreme care to preserve the insulation integrity of the extended wires. Simple finger twisted wire connections wound up in electrical tape is not likely to be suitable. You would also have to preserve the special connectors on the ends of the wires be able to still connect them into the high voltage power supply board.

Comment: In any case I would not recommend changing this from the typical 4" to 6" lead length showing on the panel to many feet of wire.